# How do I create a single object and push multiple key-pair values inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to create an object with multiple key-pair values inside.

The values I'm using will be be coming from an API and I'm trying to convert the response into a single object.

My code:

```
json_users.forEach(function (user){
    var user_name = user.name;
    var object_user = {user_name: null};

    temp_collection.push(object_user);
})
```

The kind of result I want

```
{"key_1":val_1, "key_2", val_2}
```

The result I get

```
[{
    0: {
        .....
    }, 
    1: {
        .....
    }
}]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are starting with. Keys in Objects are unique, so looping over an array and setting `user_name` on the same object will only set one `user_name`. It might help if you can give an example of the `json_users`. If you are trying to use `user_name` as the key, put it in brackets `{[user_name]: values}`

Comment: Could you please add an example of this code you’re looping through, as we don’t know what you started with.

Comment: I simply want to be able to create an object that will contain values without an index when pushing to it. Like `{"k1":v1, "k2":v2} instead if {[ [0] {"k1":v1} [1] {"k2":v2} ]}

Comment: @M. Duisenbayev  has already answered my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var resultObject = {};
json_users.forEach(function (user, index){
    var user_name = user.name;
    var object_user = {user_name: null};

    resultObject["key" + (index + 1)] = object_user;
});
```

resultObject will be what you need. Instead of "key" + (index + 1) you can use user.id or something like that. This way you will have a dictionary of users, where keys will be IDs and values will be user objects

Comment: Thank you! This solves my problem. I am pretty new to javascript since I'm mostly developing in Java for android app development so I'm not really familiar with how to manipulate objects and arrays so well.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn’t use `.push()` - this is creating the array. Try this instead:

```
var temp_collection = {};
json_users.forEach((user, index) => temp_collection[`key_${index}`] = user.name);
```

This iterates through the array `json_user` and adds a new property to the `temp_collection` object with the `name` property of each object in the array.

The above does use ES6 arrows and template literals though, so here’s a more widely accepted version:

```
json_users.forEach(function(user, index) {
    temp_collection["key_" + index] = user.name;
})
```

Comment: My question is already answered, but I'm pretty sure your answer works as well. Thank you also for explaining it in detail.